# how do i get an image id from a clicked image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I have a list of images that are pulled from a database and loaded into a ListView in ASP. I have a JQuery click function attached to each image that is generated. What I need to do is somehow get the id of the image that is clicked, but right now, I dont see a way to attach an ID to each image.

The ListView is populated from a SQLSource that has the columns ID, UserName, Photo. The item template uses username and photo to display the list, but will not let me set the ID using Eval("fieldName").

What I'm trying to do is: when the user clicks the image, the ID associated with that image is grabbed by JQuery, which opens up another window and uses that ID has part of a querystring. Ex:

window.open("anotherpage.aspx?id=" + imgID);

Here is the jquery I have right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            $('[class=originalPhoto]').click(function (event) {
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                var windowName = "popup";

                window.open("test.aspx");
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
 </script>
```

And the listview:

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="photoList" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="employeePicsSource" DataKeyNames="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <center>
                    <p>
                    <table border="0" width="1000" cellpadding="10" class="personnelCell">                        
                        <tr>
                            <td width="25%"><%#Eval("FullName") %></td>
                            <td width="25%"><%#Eval("ADGUID") %></td>
                            <td width="25%" align="center"><asp:Image runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl='<%#GetImageURL((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")) %>' 
                            Width="200" CssClass="originalPhoto" /></td>
                            <td width="25%"><asp:Image runat="server" Width="96" Height="96" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </p>
                    </center>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="employeePicsSource" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Employee_Photos_DevConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT [FullName], [ADGUID], [Photo], [ID] FROM [Employee_AndPhoto]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: where you're establishing each image, try adding an id to the element the image goes in, such as `<img id="%imageNameNoSpaces%" ...` then you can use your jQuery to easily call for `$('img').attr('id');` or however you itterate through your images, point is, ten an id would be in a set place

Comment: oh you know what, that was my first instinct, but asp image controls wont let you do it. so i used a standard html img and that allowed me to tag it, but now the javascript isn't firing

Comment: probably because i was still using the asp CssClass attribute. changed it to class and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way you get the href you can have the id as well

```
$('.originalPhoto').click(function (event) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var windowName = "popup";

    window.open("test.aspx?id="+id);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

As jostster says, you also need to add the id to you image, something like

```
id='Convert.ToString((int)DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "ID"))'
```

Comment: He also needs to add the html attribute `id` to the image tags.